# Какие существуют особенности текста-описания?

Tags: егэ, обучение, анализ-текста, текст

Назовите особенности текста-описания, а то ничего толкового не могу найти в интернете и можете пожалуйста их показать наглядно на примере:

> Грушницкий – юнкер. Он только год в службе, носит, по особенному роду франтовства, толстую солдатскую шинель. У него георгиевский солдатский крестик. Он хорошо сложен, смугл и черноволос; ему на вид можно дать двадцать пять лет, хотя ему едва ли двадцать один год. Он закидывает голову назад, когда говорит, и поминутно крутит усы левой рукой, ибо правою опирается на костыль. Говорит он скоро и вычурно: он из тех людей, которые на все случаи жизни имеют готовые пышные фразы, которых просто прекрасное не трогает и которые важно драпируются в необыкновенные чувства, возвышенные страсти и исключительные страдания.

Comment: Не закрывайте вопрос.  Мне тоже хочется узнать: (1) Какие в действительности существуют особенности текста-описания? (2) Как правильно отвечать  на этот вопрос, то есть как принято отвечать на него в школе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Описание – это словесное изображение предмета, явления, события. В описании перечисляются и раскрываются основные признаки выбранного предмета. Цель – представить  образ, который легко вообразить в красках.

Текст описания обычно состоит из следующих частей:

общая характеристика предмета, общее впечатление;

признаки, детали;

общая оценка предмета.

Описание может быть портретным, пейзажным; объектом описания может быть все что угодно – и человек, и его эмоциональное состояние, и животное, и растение, и место (город, отельный дом, парк, деревня), и погода. Речевая особенность – преобладание существительных, прилагательных, наречий, минимум действия и статичность текста.

Описательный текст отвечает на вопросы «какой? какие?» (какой предмет описывается? как выглядит? каковы его качества и свойства?).

Какой предмет описывается? – *литературный персонаж Грушницкий;*

Каков предмет? – Грушницкий – юнкер, франт, носит толстую солдатскую шинель, георгиевский солдатский крестик. *Детали внешности: хорошо сложен, смугл и черноволос; ему на вид можно дать двадцать пять лет, хотя ему едва ли двадцать один год. Он закидывает голову назад, когда говорит, и поминутно крутит усы левой рукой, ибо правою опирается на костыль.* Особенности речи:  говорит скоро и вычурно, на все случаи жизни имеет готовые пышные фразы,он из тех, кто важно драпируется в необыкновенные чувства, возвышенные страсти и исключительные страдания. Всё это - **литературный портрет**. Внешность можно сфотографировать и перечислить её детали.

Есть **подсказка** по различению типов речи:

Типы речи – это способы изложения, которые решают следующие авторские задачи:

повествование – динамично отражает действительность, рассказывает о ее событиях (действиях героев); **повествование – это клип, кино, смена кадров;**

**описание** – изображает статичную действительность, изучает со всех сторон интересующий объект; **описание чаще всего – это фотография, застывший кадр**; бывает и описание чувств, их снять на кадр не получится, но перечислить детали возможно.

рассуждение – ищет причинно-следственные связи между событиями и явлениями, выражает мнение автора, «потому что…»; **это тезис, доказательство, пример.** Так как это речь, то **сфотографировать её нельзя.**